# Selenium C # ngwebelement is timing out

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, protractor, protractor-net

I am facing script execution issue. This has started all of sudden.
I am using protractor wrapper class over selenium. Ie,

```
driver = new Chromedriver("driver path", option);
ngdriver=new ngWebDriver(driver);
ngdriver.Navigate().GotoURL("url");
ngdriver.IgnoreSynchronization=false;
ngdriver.findelement(By.xpath("xpath ")).Click
```

--> this step is failing

When I run a command(`ngdriver.findelement(By.xpath("xpath "`)).Click ) for clicking on ngWebElement using protractor wrapper class in Selenium C# I am getting Script Timeout (session info: chrome 90.0.4430.212)

This works fine when I do "`ngdriver.ignoreSynchronization=true`". But I don't want this solution because there is lot of change I need to make in terms of synchronization. So far protractor wrapper class used to take care of it.

Please help if anyone aware about this issue.

Url and elements are confidential and hence I am not posting the actual Url

Comment: More sample code would be helpful. I.e. what is the command you run for clicking?  A clearer picture please.

Comment: *When I run a command for clicking on ngWebElement using protractor wrapper class in Selenium C# I am getting Script Timeout* - then might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what C# wrapper is but `ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated from protractor. `waitForAngularEnabled` should be used instead. Maybe its different in C# library...

what both commands do, they instruct protractor to wait until angular finished polling tasks on the background. There are really 2 ways to avoid these tasks - one is to run `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` and then manually handle all waiting, or to fix the application and fix the code that causes these tasks to run for too long. There is no really other way

Comment: When IgnoreSynchronization=false that mean ngwedriver will be in active state. by default code has synchronization capability. It used to work till few weeks back but not now. the advantage of ngwebdriver is you dont have to use any wait mechanism while scripting . ngWebdriver used to take care of synchronization

Comment: read my answer @Manoj it is no longer a feature in protractor for like last 2 years

Comment: thanks for replying. However, browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) command is not available in c# visual studio protractor plugin. The available one are driver.WaitForAngular(); but it is not helping for synchronization ,  the code will work with explicit wait only with selenium but not the protractor wrapper class but it will take huge round of rework effort for me , Hence I am looking for an alternative for ignoreSynchronization =false